# react native force light mode in android app

Tags: android, react-native, android-layout, themes, android-dark-theme

when I run my react native app in the emulator (pixel android 10), I noticed that the app change the white background to black when the phone set to dark mode.
this made hard to read the black text or anything else.
is there a way that forces the app to run in light theme despite the OS in dark or light mode

```
"react-native-appearance": "^0.3.2",
```

Comment: in other words how to disable dark mode from android app

Comment: would setting up a background color for the particular component help?

Comment: no , its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this 
`Appearance.set({ colorScheme: 'light' });`

Comment: It gets undefined there are no methods like Appearance.set  in react native now

Comment: I must say `.set()` method is a hard one to find a description for, at least in the docs. Good find!

Comment: @ArunkumarK it's not available in 'react-native'. Install 'react-native-appearance' and import from there.